# The Requested Item is not found , Google In App Billing ,V:5

Tags: java, android, kotlin, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm Unable to get the item on my in-app purchase bottom sheet of google.

> **Error: say item not found**

Even the item **exists**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure your product key is the same and in ACTIVE State.
- You Upload the signed apk on the google play console.
- On the internal testing.
- After uploading to internal testing add emails to your testing list.
- Accept the invite and move to your testing.

For more, you can visit there:
https://www.answertopia.com/java-android/a-java-android-in-app-purchasing-tutorial/